# How to place SplitView in the header of a phone in UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am using SplitView in a desktop app. It works fine. Now, I want to use it in a phone with Windows 10. I want to avoid the permanent vertical panel because of the small screen of a phone. I would like to hide the this bar, like for example Calendar App of Windows Mobile 10 does.Is it possible? I cannot find the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set DisplayMode property to "Overlay".

`DisplayMode="Overlay"`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a device type enumeration to keep track of the devices,ie wether its a phone or tablet like this

```
public enum DeviceTypeEnum
{
    Phone = 1,
    Tablet = 2
}
```

You can identify whether its a tablet or phone using the following code

```
var  deviceType = ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons") ? DeviceTypeEnum.Phone : DeviceTypeEnum.Tablet;
```

Now using the devicetype property you can do whatever applicable to phone and tablet.

In your case you could write a enum to visibility converter which be visible if the device type is tablet.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe the question was not clear. What I am trying is to show only the hamburger button in phone devices, without the vertical bar with all other controls. If the user clicks it, then it would show the menu. Like the Calendar app of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Just created a sample project for others to follow while doing SplitView in both mobile and desktop: https://github.com/nicruo/Splitview-UWP